# Why isn't star colored completely?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

```
    from turtle import *
    o=Turtle()
    d=Screen()
    o.begin_fill()
    o.width("2")
    o.color("yellow")
    extent1=150**2*3.14
    print(extent1)
    o.circle(radius=150,extent=extent1,steps=10)
    o.end_fill()
```

Comment: What do you mean "colored completely"? It would help if you could [edit] your question to include a screenshot of the image that you see and what you're expecting/

Comment: i ran the code and this was the result what is the problem ?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xR5Or.png

Comment: In Tkinter (and therefore also the Turtle module that uses it), self-intersecting polygons have different results on different platforms due to differences on how the platform's graphics system defines the inside of a polygon.  There's nothing you can do to change this.

Comment: Yes the result doesn't color inside the boundary of the sides of the polygon..i'd like trying to modify it..but I've understood the question

Answer (score 0):

@jasonharper's comment is spot-on (+1).  To make the filled star appear the same on both architectures, draw (then fill) just the perimeter of the star you want:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience
turtle.color("yellow")
turtle.begin_fill()

for _ in range(11):
    turtle.forward(64)
    turtle.right(98.2)
    turtle.forward(64)
    turtle.left(130.91)

turtle.end_fill()
turtle.hideturtle()

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

Comment: 'from turtle import *
o=Turtle()
d=Screen()                                                                                                              o.begin_fill()
for i in range(0,6):
    o.forward(45)
    o.right(60)
    o.forward(45)
    o.left(120)
o.end_fill()
o.hideturtle()

d.mainloop() '